# How to connect a Button to the Checkboxes in a GridView, and delete the selected rows from the GridView(ticked via CheckBoxes integrated in GridView)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, datatable

I have created a Gridview containing data extracted from a TextBox. I have a "Delete Link" on the GridView to delete the row from the GridView if required.

Now I want to make some changes to it. Instead of the **"Delete link"** on the GridView, I want Checkboxes on each row of the GridView. Outside the GridView, there should be a Button. On clicking that button, the rows selected via the Checkbox on the Gridview should be deleted.

**What changes has to be made to the below code to implement this functionality?** Please specify the changes clearly.

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <br />

        Employee 
        ID&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Employee Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        Salary&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add to Grid" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Export data to Database" OnClick="Button2_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="EmpID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
        PageSize="5" AllowPaging="true" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" Width="800">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("EmpID")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("EmpName")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Salary">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("EmpSalary")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpSalary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Modify" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit">
            <ControlStyle Width="50" />
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete these records?');">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <p style="width: 799px">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" 
            Text="Delete Checked items" Width="162px" />
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
            Width="580px">
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>
    </p>
    </form>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Sample.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["constring"]);
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    DataRow dr1;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "";
        //lbldbmsg.Text = "";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("EmpID");
            dt.Columns.Add("EmpName");
            dt.Columns.Add("EmpSalary");
            Session["reptable"] = dt;
            GridData();            
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridData();
    }

    void GridData()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["reptable"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridData();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string EmpID;

        EmpID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        TextBox EmpName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmpName");
        TextBox EmpSalary = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmpSalary");


        if (Session["reptable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Clear();
            dt1 = Session["reptable"] as DataTable;
            for (int i = 0; i <= dt1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr;
                if (dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString() == EmpID)
                {
                    dr = dt1.Rows[i];
                    dt1.Rows[i].Delete();
                }
            }
            Session.Remove("reptable");
            Session["reptable"] = dt1;

            //add that updated row here
            dt = (DataTable)Session["reptable"];
            dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["EmpID"] = EmpID;
            dr1["EmpName"] = EmpName.Text;
            dr1["EmpSalary"] = EmpSalary.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
            Session.Remove("reptable");
            Session["reptable"] = dt;
        }

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridData();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string EmpID;
        EmpID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        if (Session["reptable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Clear();
            dt1 = Session["reptable"] as DataTable;
            for (int i = 0; i <= dt1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr;
                if (dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString() == EmpID)
                {
                    dr = dt1.Rows[i];
                    dt1.Rows[i].Delete();
                    //dt1.Rows.Remove(dr);
                }
            }
            Session.Remove("reptable");
            Session["reptable"] = dt1;
        }
        GridData();
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridData();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["reptable"];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["EmpID"] = TextBox1.Text;
        dr["EmpName"] = TextBox2.Text;
        dr["EmpSalary"] = TextBox3.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session.Remove("reptable");
        Session["reptable"] = dt;
        GridData();
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
    }

    //Bulk Insert data into sql server database
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["reptable"];
        //Upload data to Database using bulk copy
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["constring"]);
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Emp";          //table name
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);

        //remove data after insert
        dt.Clear();
        Session["reptable"] = dt;
        GridData();
        Label1.Text = "All Records Inserted successfully into the database";

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

**ASPX Code**:

Add checkbox control in item template of your gridview..

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdelete" runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**C# code**:

```
   protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        //Finiding checkbox control in gridview for particular row
        CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkdelete");
        //Condition to check checkbox selected or not
        if (chkdelete.Checked)
        {
            if (Session["reptable"] != null)
            {
                string EmpID = GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1.Clear();
                dt1 = Session["reptable"] as DataTable;
                for (int i = 0; i <= dt1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr;
                    if (dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString() == EmpID)
                    {
                        dr = dt1.Rows[i];
                        dt1.Rows[i].Delete();
                        //dt1.Rows.Remove(dr);
                    }
                }
                //Session.Remove("reptable");
                Session["reptable"] = dt1;
            }
           
        }
    }
  GridData();
}
```

Comment: What do I have to code inside this:       if(chkdelete.Checked)
 {
 //code for deleting the row
 }

Comment: Thanks Coder! May God bless you.

Comment: I'm getting an error message. (Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands 'string' and 'int'). The Error is on line:    if(dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString() == EmpID)

Comment: An Error is getting is getting displayed: 'The name "EmpID" does not exist in the current context'.

Comment: copy the line int EmpId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value); and paste it inside that if(sessio[]) statement..

Comment: Still Error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands 'string' and 'int'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24890/discussion-between-coder-and-fahhad)

Comment: Do you think EmpId and EmpID should be differently specified, as you have specified in the code?

Answer (score 0):

change in ASPX:

from

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("EmpID")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

to

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("EmpID")%>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkdelete" value='<%#Eval("EmpID")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Note the single quote in

> value='<%#Eval("EmpID")%>'

Code for code behind:

```
   protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    for(int i = 0; i< GridView1.Rows; i++)
{
If((GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ckhdelete") as CheckBox) != null && (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ckhdelete") as CheckBox).checked)
{
//Delete dataRow with EmpID = convertToInt( (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ckhdelete") as CheckBox).value);
}
}
        }
```

EDIT:
This will not work in case of paging, you will sessions or place a limitation the current page's rows will only be delete.